# How do I get Magento to always give the /catalog/product/view/id/ style url for products?

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting

I want Magento to always generate product urls in the format:

> www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/123/s/product-name.html

instead of the rewritten

> www.example.com/product-name.html

The reason for this is mainly so that I don't have to worry if something happens to all my rewrites, or so I can feel free to truncate and rebuild core_url_rewrite if something goes wrong and it gets too big.

I don't want to stop using rewritten urls entirely. I like them for categories. I have fewer categories, and I very rarely change the names. I hate feeling like I can't change the name of a product because it will make the core_url_rewrite table grow and mess up any backlinks I've generated if I lose my rewrites. Also, I still want my current urls to work for as long as possible along with the /product/view/id urls.

Is there an easy way to do this without rewriting methods that I'm missing?

Or do I have to override some getProductUrl method? It looks like the answer lies in the getProductUrl() method in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product? That class seems to use the getProductUrl() method in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url.

But again, if there's some simple configuration setting that would do the trick, I'd rather do that.

Answer (score 0):

Magento handled it by own. Please follow the below steps. 
1.Login to the admin panel
2. Then System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Catalog >> Search Engine Optimization
3. Then Change the settings as per your requirement 
4. As per your current requirement "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" will be YES 
5. Then try to reindex full Via SSH.

Hope it will works.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think that setting does what I'm asking.

Comment: I guess its does as its works for me earlier.  Bur keep in mind when you are trying to get product url from non category page it will not return category product url.in that case you need to load product via category collection.  Like load category product then filter by conditions.

Comment: Also you can create custom product url redirect either via admin or pro-grammatically.For Dynamic way use http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-url-rewrites/ Or via admin http://blog.beetleweb.com/2012/10/creating-custom-magento-url-rewrites/

Comment: @AvikRoy Can you please give reference of how to load product via category collection if it from non category page